# SQL Statement - quantity of 1st table minus the summation of quantity of 2nd table

Tags: sql, subquery

I have 2 tables:

Purchase Orders:

```
PO #          Part #              PO Qty
S40000010     103-137                10
```

PO Receipts

```
PO #          Part #         Received Qty
S40000010     103-137              5
S40000010     103-137              3
```

How to write the sql statement to extract the following:

```
PO #          Part #            Balance Qty
S40000010     103-137               2
```

Comment: You should include what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```sql
SELECT po, part, SUM(qty) balance
  FROM
(
  SELECT po, part, qty
    FROM PurchaseOrders
  UNION ALL
  SELECT po, part, -1 * qty 
    FROM POReceipts
) q
 GROUP BY po, part;
```

or

```sql
SELECT p.po, p.part, p.qty - COALESCE(r.qty, 0) balance
  FROM PurchaseOrders p LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT po, part, SUM(qty) qty 
    FROM POReceipts
   GROUP BY po, part
) r 
  ON p.po = r.po AND p.part = r.part;
```

Output:

```
|        PO |    PART | BALANCE |
|-----------|---------|---------|
| S40000010 | 103-137 |       2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9208e9/4)** demo

Further reading:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)
- [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)